# Secure field in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I have a secured field on Dynamics CRM

I was wondering when I select “share secured fields” button from record and share secured field with another user.

1)Does this share the secured field for that particular record ONLY or does this share the secured field to ALL records that have that secured field?

2)Also if user has update permissions to the secured field can they share the field to other users or teams if they can what is the best way to restrict?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this share the secured field for that particular record ONLY or does this share the secured field to ALL records that have that secured field?

Not for all records, user will be sharing the secured fields of that particular record with their peers they want. The popup header clearly calls this out. [Read more](https://myencounterwithcrm.wordpress.com/2014/12/03/crmshared-secured-field/)

[image]

> Also if user has update permissions to the secured field can they share the field to other users or teams if they can what is the best way to restrict?

There is a separate privilege in security roles to control users from sharing the secured fields. Remove that privilege to restrict them. This is different from FLS rights in fields. [Read more](https://garethtuckercrm.com/tag/field-level-security/)

[image]